# The most robust way to setState in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have a firebase realtime database, a JSON based no sql database, I have 5 fields in that database, storing these:

```
field 1: STRING
field 2: STRING
field 3: STRING
field 4: STRING
field 5: ARRAY OF OBJECTS
```

so that database with real example looks something like this:

```
name: STRING
age: NUMBER
email: STRING
phoneNumber: STRING
skills: OBJECT[]
```

now I am downloading all these info from the firebase as a single variable(`var`) called 
`snapshot.val()`. and then updating all the states using `setState` at once like this:

```
this.setState({
  state_name: snapshot.val().name,
  state_age: snapshot.val().age,
  state_email: snapshot.val().email,
  state_phoneNumber: snapshot.val().phoneNumber,
  state_skills: snapshot.val().skills
});
```

now this statement works fine if all the values are there in the database and it also works fine if the strings aren't there in the database but it runs into an error if the skills field is `undefined` in the database.

So `setState` doesn't throw an error when strings are undefined but it does throw error when arrays are undefined. it happened even with simple string array. Now if one field doesn't exist and an error is thrown, the entire `setState` fails, so in summary, if multiples states are being updated at once and one of the state upadate fails with an exception or error, all the updates fail and I have been updating such delicate data with separate `setState` statements with only one state being updated inside its own try catch block. So to update multiple states that have the potential to crash, I am using multiple try catch blocks. something like this:

```
try {
  this.setState({
    ownerNameValue: snapshot.val().owner_name,
  });
} catch {}

try {
  this.setState({
    phoneNumberValue: snapshot.val().phone_number,
  });
} catch {}

try {
  this.setState({
    specialityValue: snapshot.val().specialty,
  });
} catch {}

try {
  if (snapshot.val().services != undefined) {
    this.setState({
      selectedOptionSerivce: snapshot.val().services,
    });
  }
} catch {}

try {
  if (snapshot.val().home_service != undefined) {
    this.setState({
      selectedOption: snapshot.val().home_service,
    });
  }
} catch {}
```

Now is there a more robust and efficient way to achieve this?

Some way to update all the states at once and not crash if one of the state has its value as undefined or simply fails. So that way, the states that run into no problems, get updated, but the states that run into exceptions and errors, simply get discarded without showing any error.

so it will be something like this:

```
field 1: STRING ->> state updated
field 2: STRING ->> state updated
field 3: STRING ->> state updated
field 4: STRING ->> state updated
field 5: undefined ->> state update FAILED (an array of objects was excepted)
```

**NOTICE:** this question is not limited to firebase, its about `setState` handling exceptions and errors of all kind.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, you want to skip updating pieces of state that are coming back as `undefined` from `firebase`?

Comment: @goto1 pretty much but also being ready for any exceptions and errors that can cause the `setState` statement to crash

Comment: `setState` wouldn't throw an error if you set a piece of state to `undefined` - the reason why you're seeing an error is probably because you're not handling a case where your `state.someProperty` is equal to `undefined`

Comment: @goto1 ah, can you clarify even more with a detailed answer? that will be very much appreciated

Comment: sure, writing the answer right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign to skills an empty array when it is undefined like this:

```js
this.setState({
  state_name: snapshot.val().name,
  state_age: snapshot.val().age,
  state_email: snapshot.val().email,
  state_phoneNumber: snapshot.val().phoneNumber,
  state_skills: snapshot.val().skills || [],
});
```

Comment: perfect answer, and if its just an `object` we can replace the `[]` with `null`

Comment: @AKC I am happy that you liked this answer, please don't forget to mark this as answer.

Comment: I have one question tho, what is the value is null, because I am getting an error message now by following your code, it works good but when some value is null, it creates an error message saying `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): cannot read property 'name' of null` is there a way to handle this exception as well like the the array one, I don't think the replacing `[]` with `null` for just an object works but `[]` does work for arrays

Comment: @AKC are we talking about when  state_skills is null?

Comment: yea, a null value throws an exception and the usual way to handle it, is to check before entering the value, but is there any faster and more efficient way?

Comment: @AKC this handles undefined and also null `state_skills: snapshot.val().skills || []`. Can you explain exactly what problem you have? Do you have problem on the name field? If so just use `state_name: snapshot.val().name || {},` or maybe `state_name: snapshot.val().name || "",`

Comment: I think its a completely separate problem with firebase, if they can't read data they show the error, what I can do is, I can use a function in setState and make things work

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no sense in doing something like:

```
  try {
    if (snapshot.val().home_service != undefined) {
      this.setState({
        selectedOption: snapshot.val().home_service
      });
    }
  } catch{ }
```

Calling `setState` won't crash if you set `undefined` as a value. The only case you may face an error is when you accidentally forgot to check this value inside of a lifecycle methods or `render`:

```
render() {
  return this.state.skills.map(...)
}
```

Here, if `skills` is `undefined` you'll get an error. For efficiency sake you may do something like:

```
class Some {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {...}
  }

  get skills() {
    return this.state.skills || []
  }

  render() {
    return this.skills.map(...)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to wrap `this.setState` inside of a `try/catch`. `setState` will not throw an error if you try to set some property of your state to `undefined` - this is definitely allowed.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { foo: "bar" };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        foo: undefined
      });
    }, 4000);
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.foo !== undefined ? (
      <h1>this.state.foo is not undefined</h1>
    ) : (
      <h1>this.state.foo IS undefined</h1>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("app")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

So, when you say that it "fails" because you set a piece of `state` to `undefined`, you're most likely not handling this case elsewhere in your code. This is common when you're expecting something to be an `array` and you're trying to use the `map` method, but it turns out to be `undefined`.

```js
render() {
  // this.state.skills is `undefined
  // and you're trying to use the `map` method
  // which will fail
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.skills.map(...)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

What you should do is to specify fallbacks for items that come back as `undefined`:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  updateState = () => {
    firebase()
      .then(snapshot => {
        this.setState({
          state_name: snapshot.val().name ||  '',
          state_age: snapshot.val().age || 0,
          state_email: snapshot.val().email || '',
          state_phoneNumber: snapshot.val().phoneNumber || '',
          state_skills: snapshot.val().skills || []
        })
      })
      .catch(/* handle errors appropriately */)
  }
}
```